# Is there any reset Library for CSS for just Modern Browsers?

Tags: css, css-reset

I am aiming to support just IE10+, and the newest versions of the most popular browsers.  I am wondering if there is a css reset just for those specific browsers ignoring old IE and Moz fixes.

I couldn't find any, but perhaps I have overlooked some when I was searching on Google.  I plan to create my own of course, I just don't want to redo work if there is a library out there I can utilize.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern as in HTML5 resets?

[Blue Print Framework has a nice reset](http://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css)

http://html5reset.org/

Then there is YUI,  http://code.google.com/p/reset5/...

Comment: Those were pretty close, but I want to ignore IE7, etc.  I will probably use those to assist me to create my own.  Thanks!

Comment: Reset5 seems to be the closest reset I could use with some modification.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A CSS base and reset is meant to apply to all HTML elements you use, so that the browser never has to reach into its default styles to render anything on your page. A few elements [have been removed](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/#obsolete-elements)* in HTML5, so you could remove these from your reset if any are present, but that might be over-optimizing. For what it's worth, the YUI 3 CSS base and reset account well for modern browsers.

EDIT:

- Correction: They have been marked obsolete; compliant browsers such as IE10 still need to support them, so unless you are sure your page/application will never use any of them, they should not be removed from your base/reset.

Comment: This is not for an average web application/site.  I just wanted to have one I can use to ignore most of the old IE changes.  Considering Zepto or Jquery 2.0, they are ignoring old IE fixes altogether.  Thats what I'm looking for, but I do realize it might not be out there :)

Answer (score 1):

[Normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) is worth a look as an alternative to a CSS reset.  Instead of resetting all styles, it targets the ones that need to change to change to give you sane, consistent results across browsers in a smaller file size.

This means that there is not so many styles to clutter your dev tools debugging.  It also fixes some common bugs.  It's a mainstream project, that's well maintained, focuses on modern (ie8+) browsers and is used by some high profile sites.

Read [more about it here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/).

Comment: Thanks, but not the exact answer I was looking for!